# An method for separating people and background in images

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I am looking for a way to separate the part of an image that contains a person from the background in an image.  It does not have to be very accurate, rough borders will do too.  It can be an algorithm, a software lib (pref. open source), or even a reference to a relevant AI or image processing material.  Having to train the solver is acceptable.  However, the final application have to be reasonably lightweight, as it would have to run on a smartphone.

Comment: anything really usable in that field would drain the battery pretty fast... usually this is solved in a client-server fashion i.e. the phone sends the picture to a server and gets the result from the server back and displays it/whatever...

Comment: @Yahia that'll work too, but nevertheless, the receiving server will have to run pretty fast, no time for lengthy calculations.  If possible, better to do the hard work in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Start with [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). It's an open-source computer-vision library that already contains some algorithms for that. Try what it's got and see if it's good enough for your needs.

The “[Learning OpenCV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134)” book will give good introduction into computer vision and machine learning.

Comment: you write "contains some algorithms for that".  Could you please post links or refs to relevant algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for algorithms then check this out http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/

they have also some source code samples (although for Mathematica)...